# Can't seem to display iframe properly in IE8?

Tags: css, mobile, iframe, internet-explorer-8, media-queries

I have a site here: [Campus Tour](http://webfro.gs/south/tour) that I'm trying to display in an iframe as well. The goal here is to be able to see exactly what a student is seeing when the student is viewing the tour on a mobile device.

Here is the iPhone viewport: [iPhone Viewport](http://webfro.gs/south/tour/viewport_iphone5.html)

It displays properly in Chrome, but I can't get it to display in IE8. When viewed in IE8, the iframe displays the site in full site mode, and doesn't adhere to the mobile CSS.

**Here's my iframe code:**

```
<div align="center" style="position: fixed; margin-top: 2%; margin-left: 12%; border: 5px solid #f60; width: auto; height: auto;">

                <h2 style="font-weight:bold; background-color: #f60; color: #fff;">iPhone 5 Display</h2>
                    <iframe style="width:568px; height: 320px; " src="http://webfro.gs/south/tour" frameborder="0"></iframe>
            </div>
```

I've Googled my heart out and read about Quirks mode, and so forth, but not quite sure how to apply it. I'm not sure that's the right solution either.

What more information do you need in order to assist here?

Comment: re your remark about quirks mode: No, quirks mode is never the right answer to anything.

Comment: That's why I didn't implement it. Any ideas?

Comment: yep, patience!  :-) ... I've just posted an answer.

Comment: Is there a practical application for displaying the site in an iframe this way?  If it's purely for testing purposes, working in IE8 is irrelevant.  Focusing on specific device resolutions is not a very future proof way of going about doing responsive design:  http://thesiteslinger.com/blog/responsive-design-why-youre-doing-it-wrong/

Comment: It has to display in IE8 because that's our corporate browser. That's the only reason. It sucks, but we have too much other software that relies on IE8 to work. We're working on an upgrade now that should allow for HTML5 ready browsers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is that IE8 doesn't support CSS media queries, which you're using to change the layout according to the size of the viewport.

If you need to support IE8 for this, the best solution is to use a polyfill script like [Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond), which backports support for the media query syntax into IE8.

Comment: What do you recommend for image support here? The site properly displays in the iframe, however the main image on some screens stretches vertically. Any thoughts? Here's a link: [iPhone5 Viewport](http://webfro.gs/south/tour/viewport_iphone5.html)